# Android Best Practise to nullify unused objects ? Is it Good or it have disadvantages?

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I am new to Android,

Is it good to null all objects in ondestroy() method ?

example :

```
public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
TextView tv = null;  
private static int mValue;   // a static member here

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText((mValue != 0) ? 
    ("Left-over value = " + mValue) : "This is a new instance");
setContentView(tv);
}

public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
tv = null; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, it *shouldn't* have any benefit.  However, nulling references in an activity can help mitigate the effects of memory leaks that you otherwise have no control over, such as [this one in the Google Maps API](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8472).

Whether you should always do this to protect against future memory leaks of this sort is a matter of opinion.  You have to weigh the cost of maintaining the extra code against the probably minimal benefit.

Answer (score -1):

It is completely unnecessary.  The objects will be garbage collected automatically.

Comment: That is not true at all, they are only collected when there are no references to it anymore so nullifying is a good practise. Only objects you create as a local variable don't need to be nullified cause they are destroyed at the end of the method